# Jest Setup and share global variables

Tags: jestjs

I am using Jest to write Puppeteer tests and I want to do a single time setup(of opening a browser) and share it across all the tests.

The setup I need to do is returns a promise.

I tried used `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` and set `global.browser`

But this `global.browser` is not available

If I set it in the global config of Jest, I can write custom logic of setting the browser object

Like event If I declare `__BROWSER__` I cant set it

```
__BROWSER__ = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    dumpio: true,
    devtools: false
  });
```

Comment: You need to do this in the setup.js file that is referenced in the jest config

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208608/why-cant-get-the-global-variable-which-was-set-in-globalsetup-in-test-code/54344676#54344676